Can longitudinal/transverse phonons propagate along any direction in the crystal? Interpreting 2D centered rectangular crystal dispersion curves

So I'm looking at the above centered rectangular lattice with atoms of mass $M$ and nearest neighbor interaction strength $A = -\kappa$. The differential equation governing the system is
\begin{align}
    M\ddot{\vec{u}} = \kappa\sum_{j=1}^{4}\Big[\big[\vec{u}(\vec{R}_{mn}+\vec{m}_j,t) - \vec{u}(\vec{R}_{mn},t)\big]\cdot\hat{m}_j\Big]\hat{m}_j
\end{align}
Where $\vec{R}_{mn}$ indexes the center reference atom at $\vec{R}_{mn} = a(m\hat{x}+n\hat{y})$ and $\vec{m}_j$ is the four nearest-neighbor positions
\begin{equation}
\vec{m}_j = \pm\frac{a}{2}(\hat{x}\pm\hat{y})
\end{equation}
I found that the oscillation matrix's eigenvectors were
\begin{equation}
\vec{u}_{\pm} = (1,\pm 1)
\end{equation}
with normal frequencies
\begin{equation}
\omega_\pm(k_x,k_y) = 2\sqrt{\frac{\kappa}{M}}\Bigg|\text{sin}\bigg[\frac{(k_x\pm k_y)a}{4}\bigg]\Bigg|
\end{equation}
Hopefully the previous results are correct. My questions are, how do I identify the longitudinal vs. transverse branches? Are they a subjective thing where I can choose an arbitrary direction of propagation and the longitudinal mode propagates that way, but then how do I identify which branch corresponds to longitudinal and which to transverse? Or can longitudinal waves only propagate down specific symmetry directions? This is probably a very dumb question so I'm sorry about that. I figure it's related to a superposition over all the modes
\begin{equation}
\vec{u}(\vec{R}_{mn},t) = \sum_{\vec{k},\pm}C_{\vec{k},\pm}e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{R}_{mn}}e^{-i\omega_{\pm}(\vec{k})t}\vec{u}_{\pm}
\end{equation}
